# Incorrect Determinant calculated by Math.Net Matrix<double>.Determinant()

Tags: c#, .net, newtons-method

I'm writing a program that uses Newton-Raphson method to solve a convex non-linear system of equations. At one point, the value of the jacobian matrix of the system has a determinant that is calculated as being equal to 0, but when I transpose the matrix into LibreOffice Calc, and calculate the determinant, I find that it is non-0.

Here are images of the matrix and determinant in Visual Studio and LibreOffice Calc:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So far, I have tried using elementary row operations to reduce the matrix into a diagonal matrix. This is possible which indicates that the matrix is non-singular, and the determinant is non-0.

Here is the matrix after having several row operations applied to it:

[image]

I have considered that the discrepancy may be the result of floating point errors, but I don't know how to check this. Also, the size of the discrepancy makes this seem unlikely.

**Edit:**
I've  been trying to reproduce the results above, but I have been having difficulties. The following code (based on the matrix above) prints the determinant -4.10496081041529E+88 to console:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using System;
namespace MatrixDeterminantExample {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Matrix<double> m = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(4, 4);
            m[0, 0] = 3.13E+17;
            m[0, 1] = 0;
            m[0, 2] = 0;
            m[0, 3] = -5.70602814759918E+027;
            m[1, 0] = 0;
            m[1, 1] = 1250000000000;
            m[1, 2] = 0;
            m[1, 3] = -1250000000000;
            m[2, 0] = 0;
            m[2, 1] = 0;
            m[2, 2] = 4.16E+23;
            m[2, 3] = -2529352014499.78;
            m[3, 0] = -5.71E+27;
            m[3, 1] = -1250000000000;
            m[3, 2] = -2529352014499.77;
            m[3, 3] = 1.03841786481613E+038;
            Console.WriteLine(m.Determinant());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A reproducible example - with data and code - would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation, I discovered that the issue here is has to do with numerical stability. The conditioning number of the matrix m in the code above is 8.3073429186615851E+25. This suggests that the discrepancy in the determinant between Calc and Math.Net is the result of rounding errors in the copy-paste operation being magnified by the poorly-conditioned matrix. (Rounding errors exist in the copy-paste operation since I am copying the decimal approximation of the doubles from Visual Studio to Calc rather than the actual binary value).

In addition to the previously mentioned copy-paste error, it is also possible that Calc and Math.Net calculate determinants differently, and the poor conditioning of the matrix is resulting in very large floating point errors.